# On click show/hide contents for brands list

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, directory

I would like my brand directory to have a click event. So if a visitor clicks 'A' for example, all brands within A are shown. I have the below code which collates the brands - however, the script I am trying to use to get the click event does not seem to work. Can anyone help? Below is the code exactly as it is in the PHTML file (I am using the script inline).

***CODE***

```
<div class="brands-mob" style="padding-left:5px;">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($alph as $letter => $children): ?>
        <li style="float:left;width:100%;">
        <span style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:20px;"><?php echo $letter; ?></span>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($children as $child){
                $skin_url = $child->getImageUrl(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $child->getURL();?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName();?>">
                        <span class="brand-name"><?php echo $child->getName();?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <?php   }?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>

$("UL UL").css("display", "none");

$(".title").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next("UL").toggle(); 
});
</script>
```

Can anyone please suggest an edit to my code to achieve this effect?

[image: Selfridges Mobile Brand Directory]

Answer (score 0):

Replace above code with below code and check,

```
   <div class="brands-mob" style="padding-left:5px;">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($alph as $letter => $children): ?>
            <li style="float:left;width:100%;">
            <span class="title" style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:20px;"><?php echo $letter; ?></span>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($children as $child){
                    $skin_url = $child->getImageUrl(); ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $child->getURL();?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName();?>">
                            <span class="brand-name"><?php echo $child->getName();?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <?php   }?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>

    $("ul ul").css("display", "none");

    $(".title").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
    });
    </script>
```

Remove cache.

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. I managed to get it working by putting $j rather than just the $ symbol. So presumably it was some kind of conflict... Thanks again.

Comment: Above code is working code, I have tested. You can use this code.

Comment: You can accept as answer if your issue resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by using $j to define the variable. Appears to be a conflict issue.